# Repeat Header/ template Kendo Export PDF start on page 2 Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui-angular2, export-to-pdf

i am still new in angular and typescript, basically, based on the component documentation, i tried the example from this url https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/export/pdf-export/.
Based on the source code from the example in the documentation at line below:

```
<div class="page-template"> <div class="header"> 
<div style="float: right">Page {{ pageNum }} of {{ totalPages }} . 
</div> 
Multi-page grid with automatic page breaking
</div>
```

i notice that line `Multi-page grid with automatic page breaking` will repeated on each page as image shown below

[image]

[image]

the question is, how can i hide the word `Multi-page grid with automatic page breaking` on page 1 or can i start that line on page two?. I am really sorry if i ask cliche question. I am still new in this platform. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the element when the page number is 1 in order to avoid showing it on the first page:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wxeqex-kuox4f?file=app/app.component.ts

```
<ng-template kendoGridPDFTemplate let-pageNum="pageNum" let-totalPages="totalPages">
    <div class="page-template" [ngStyle]="{ display: pageNum > 1 ? 'block' : 'none' }">
```